# How to load changed language when app is killed and open again

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the language of my app. So, i tried the below code and its working fine.

```
Resources res = getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    conf.setLocale(new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase()));
} else {
    conf.locale = new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase());
}
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("My_Lang", localeCode);
editor.apply();

Intent refresh = new Intent(this, StartupActivity.class);
startActivity(refresh);
finish();
```

Now when i kill the app and open again the language sets to default English. I'm not getting how to load Language resource by Shared Preferences. Kindly Help me to retain the language changed even the app is killed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following statement to read the data from sharedpreferences.

```
SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
String value=pref.getString("My_Lang","");
```

**In the above value is the data which is stored in the shared preference**

The updated code given below : try the below (Its a update of the answer given by @Harsha above Refer that answer and update my coding in that also)

```
 SharedPreferences pref=getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    localeCode=pref.getString("My_Lang","");


 Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                conf.setLocale(new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase()));
            } else {
                conf.locale = new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase());
            }
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            //and then                 


            setContentView(layoutId)
```

Comment: i tried this put i'm not getting any logs. tell me what to do with that value.

Comment: @vikas Acharya : i was added some of the points .Refer my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind the activity states; retrieve the `SharedPreferences` value in the `OnCreate` method of the activity, if it exists and be sure to call the `updateConfiguration` method before `setContentView` is called.

Also, on a lighter note, try calling the `editor.commit()` method rather than `editor.apply()` when you need to make sure that this preference is locally saved before restarting the activity.

Use the `editor.apply()` method when you are okay with the storing of preferences in a background thread.

Edit: Here is what you are doing wrong in your code.
You're updating the resource just before restarting the activity.

What you are instead supposed to do is to retrieve the language preference and load the resources before the setContentView is called.

So when you save the language preference..

```
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Settings", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("My_Lang", localeCode);
        editor.apply();

        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, StartupActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
```

and when you load the new language in your restarted activity

```
            Resources res = getResources();
            DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
            Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                conf.setLocale(new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase()));
            } else {
                conf.locale = new Locale(localeCode.toLowerCase());
            }
            res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
            //and then                 


            setContentView(layoutId)
```